# Combo Box Returning -1 For SelectedIndex

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to pick up a combo box's selected index. This was working absolutely fine, then all of a sudden it started returning `-1` no matter what item is selected

My code is:

**Form Code**

```
Private Sub Man_SelectedIndexChanged_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Man.SelectedIndexChanged, Units.SelectedIndexChanged
        'Set Transducer Type
        Call References.LevListAdd()
    End Sub
```

**References Module LevListAdd Sub**

```
Public Sub LevListAdd()
        Form1.Lev.Items.Clear()
        If Form1.Man.Text = "Pulsar" Then
            With Form1.Lev.Items
                .Add("Ultra Range")
                .Add("IMP Range")
                .Add("Twin Range")
            End With
        End If
    End Sub
```

This fills the combo box `lev` fine when the `Man` combo box item "Pulsar" is selected. I then want my users to click a button to generate some labels and stuff. The code is as such:

**Button Click Code**

```
 Private Sub Generate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Generate.Click
        If CheckGenerate() = False Then Exit Sub
        Dim X = CheckGenerationType(Man.SelectedIndex, Lev.SelectedIndex, Level.Checked, Volume.Checked, ListBox1.SelectedIndex,
                                    Units.SelectedIndex)
        Call ParamPage(X)
    End Sub
```

`CheckGenerate` simply checks that all boxes have been filled in. I pass the informtion from the form to the following function:

```
Public Function CheckGenerationType(Man As Integer, Lev As Integer, Level As Boolean, Volume As Boolean, TankType As Integer,
                                    MeasurementUnit As Integer) As String
Dim M As Integer
Dim L As Integer
Dim CT As Integer
Dim TT As Integer
Dim Ms As Integer

M = Man
L = Lev
TT = TankType
Ms = MeasurementUnit

If Level = True Then
    CT = 0
ElseIf Volume = True Then
    CT = 1
End If

CheckGenerationType = CStr(M) + "." + CStr(L) + "." + CStr(CT) + "." + CStr(TT) + "." + CStr(Ms)

End Function
```

When the `lev.selectedindex` parameter arrives at this function, it reads -1. Even if the user has selected any of the 3 items. Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Comment: your handler is responding to the event for `Units` and `Man` - your code will fire if they select an item in one but not the other.  Also you seem to be using default form instances which likely does not help

Comment: Doesn't If CheckGenerate() = False Then Exit Sub require an end if?

Comment: @cronos2546 not really as the statement is all on one line.

Comment: @plutonix can you explain a bit more what you mean in your comment?

Comment: Not sure I can - `Man_SelectedIndexChanged` is set to respond to the event  for **either** `Man` or `Unit`.  When that fires it is not assured that there is something selected in both, which is assumed later in `Generate_Click`.  Even so, the button click is a whole different action - the user could well UNselect stuff before they click it making it brittle.  Check for selecteditems for both controls in that click event

Comment: @plutonix, your suggestion fixed the issue. I shouldn't have been firing the code on `Unit` at all. I've changed the handler and now all is OK. If you want to put it in an answer, I'd be happy to accept.

Answer (score 1):

I've just tried your code. I get the same result (-1 in `lev.SelectedIndex`) and this was because jumped using tab through the controls my when i'm hitting the Man or Units Combobox it runs the `LevListAdd()` and then clears the Lev-ComboBox because of `Form1.Lev.Items.Clear()`.

You should think about your call `Man_SelectedIndexChanged_1` or maybe just use something like this:

```
Public Sub LevListAdd()
    If Form1.Man.Text = "Pulsar" Then
        Form1.Lev.Items.Clear()
```

instead of

```
Public Sub LevListAdd()
    Form1.Lev.Items.Clear()
    If Form1.Man.Text = "Pulsar" Then
```

And you should separate the calls from the `man` and `unit` ComboBoxes.

```
Private Sub Unit_SelectedIndexChanged_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Units.SelectedIndexChanged
    ' Do something
End Sub

Private Sub Man_SelectedIndexChanged_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Man.SelectedIndexChanged
    Form1.Lev.Items.Clear()

    Select Case Form1.Man.Text
        Case "Pulsar"
            With Form1.Lev.Items
                .Add("Ultra Range")
                .Add("IMP Range")
                .Add("Twin Range")
            End With

        Case "animals"
            With Form1.Lev.Items
                .Add("dogs")
                .Add("cats")
                .Add("birds")
            End With

    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Whilst this does fix the issue, it doesn't fix it if anything other than "Pulsar" is selected. Have upvoted though as it is an option.

Comment: The thing with "Pulsar" is your code. Do you have any other possible options for the lev-Combobox? If not, you should load the lev-ComboBox directly on the formload.

Comment: `lev` has different options depending on what `man` has inside.